# Querypath Extract Elements from Table

Tags: php, querypath

I'm using Querypath to extract name and location information from a table. I've been able to extract the table itself using innerhtml() but now I'm trying to gather the text into variables. Here's my code:

```
$searchpage = my_curl($mypage);
$searchqp = htmlqp($searchpage,'body');
$storeinfo = $searchqp->branch()->find('table[class="kwrestuls_table"]');
$storename = $storeinfo->innerhtml();
return $storename;
```

This gives me the core information that I need. Now I need to grab the store name. I've tried using:

```
$storeinfo = $searchqp->branch()->find('table[class="kwrestuls_table"]');
$storestuff = $storeinfo->innerhtml();
$storename = $storestuff->top('a[href]')->attr('href')->text();
return $storename;
```

But this isn't returning anything. Unfortunately I'm on a shared host and I can't see errors but I suspect QueryPath is throwing one.

Comment: Put at the top of your script this line to enable error reporting and display: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);` - works with all hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished my feat by using the following code:

```
$searchqp = htmlqp($searchpage,'body');
$storeinfo = $searchqp->branch()->find('table[class="kwrestuls_table"]');
$storestuff = $storeinfo->innerhtml();
$storename = htmlqp($storestuff, 'a')->eq(0)->text();
$storeaddress = htmlqp($storestuff, 'div')->eq(0)->text();
$storephones = htmlqp($storestuff, 'div')->eq(1)->text();
return $storephones;
```